# Is it possible to make a custom difficulty setting?

Tags: civilization-5, mods

I'm looking to crate my own custom difficulty setting where the computer would be as ruthless and dedicated as in Emperor, but not receive early game bonuses such as technologies or extra buildings. I'm willing to modify game files if need be, install or create a mod. Can you please help me to do that?

Comment: I believe those bonuses are what make the AI so aggressive, without those they don't become as powerful as quickly and therefore won't decide to become aggressive with you once they believe they can win a war. I find Prince is a decent way to play there is usually one AI that becomes a challenge in the late game. I have played and won games on deity and see the same bad tactics and patterns that a chieftain AI makes. As far as changing game files, I can't help you with that unfortunately.

Comment: I find King too easy, and while I don't mind at all the PC getting powerful fast, I don't enjoy being beaten to every single ancient/classical wonder simply because PC has 4 tech handicap. I would save or even increase Emperor's happiness, production gold etc. bonuses, but leave PC tech on prince/king level.

Answer (score 1):

There is a mod called:

[Really Advanced Setup](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=486324)

It allows you to control a few different things and pick the difficulty you want as well. 
Also [Smart AI](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=521955)
Will improve your AI players.

**These are the options:**

Active Civilizations
This allows you to determine which civilizations are active. Deactivate the Civs that you don't want and they won't show up. Even when using randomly selected civilizations.

Starting Bias
Allows you to set starting bias for any player to: Start Along Ocean, Start Along River, Region Priority, or Region Avoid. The region biases allow you to select up to three regions such as grass, plains, hills, desert, tundra, jungle, forest, and hybrid.

Starting Bonuses
You can set the amount of Gold, Culture, Faith, and Free Techs that each player will start with.

Starting Units
You can individually control which units each player will receive to start the game.

Terrain, Features, Resources, and Natural Wonders
There are two methods available to add these items to the map. They can be placed relative to any player's starting location. They can also be scattered randomly across the map. There are numerous options available that allow you to place as many of these various items as you wish on the map. You set the guidelines when setting up the game. The items are then added automatically when the map is made.

Starting Visibility
You can increase the amount of the map that is visible when the game starts. This option applies to all players.

New Game Options
Disable Nuclear Weapons, Always War, and Always Peace.